# Decrypted text generated by rsa

Tags: java, php, android, rsa, phpseclib

I generate rsa key in android and encrypt text and send it to server(php) with keys.

I try to decrypt ciphertext with private key but cannot because of the following error in php :

Notice: Decryption error

i think the private key is problem

My data is :

PublicKey : -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCwR8SUPzb5eLqhvXDVmtl6Q9FHSY7eJgcb23ywrX2hZaSJqaG+RuQrdrPjXjOKHHuLhis4/BVK+oMovHe8DBxlcUsVjk+/oaD0JHhJT6nchYJQ72yjo4UkZMPuczM0q2ACX1tIo/0+/qh4tbLB8/TEjVITlCuY8nEz24ZH5YcChQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

PrivateKey: 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

chiper text (orginal text is "example text"):

WuPN12rPYy+E9ozcIws/ZFP3dZiwatA24H+sz3GeOxKWKL7L8DfxAmoHDagJDy7rgbRDUrzKGKTvZsXkPpLsK+RhTHMgZAuHzrq54hUC2wfRg/omiyDeKCZFHdo5veajKzwJJSVVVqtpvL18NtFFi4tOrmNm5Dt/Blpd1zK50R0=

For information : i can decrypt it in android

Comment: Add an example here (data, encrypted data, keys) plus code

Comment: Ok i added it @JimL

Comment: You have to include the code as well, and please confirm that the received data on the PHP side is what you expect

Comment: Mr @JimL i use phpseclib in php,if i create key with this lib and use it,it's working good,but when i generate key in android and send it to server,have a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved

I had forgotten `base_decode64` ciphertext